# Can I get my tuned car back after a failed mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I tuned up a car too the hilt then went to a mission but failed the mission and boom the car was gone.

Any ideas were I could find it or have I just wasted all my money?

Comment: If the car in question is your personal (unique) car, then you should go back to your safehouse. Your car is either somewhere in the vicinity of your garage, or (sometimes) inside the garage.

Answer (score 7):

If you didn't save it in one of your garages then **NO**.

If, a car you own (that means: previously saved in a garage), is destroyed it will reappear in your garage. If an owned vehicle is lost, stolen or abandoned, it will be impounded and you need to pay a fine of $250 to get the vehicle back.

Comment: I saw something along the lines of this in the manual. To me it says: if you drive your nice shiny car to a mission but have to use a different vehicle on the mission (or for some other reason must abandon your car), the best thing you can do is *blow up your own car!*?

Comment: I just experienced that it seems like you must save an owned car **again** in your garage after it reappeared next to your house. I Just lost a car because I did not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your "owned" car will always respawn modded - Random cars will not (unless saved in a garage pre mission)

So its worth pimping out Franklins car and saving the game... - Michaels.. well play the game before throwing money at it.

Trevor. I hate trevor. He can drive his pickup truck (Nb.. I have modded it... but I did it wrong and it just spins out too easily)